# Smallest number whose digits are decreasing

Tags: python, recursion

I found a problem to implement functions that takes a positive integer n as an input and returns the smallest positive integer larger than n whose digits are decreasing and similarly for a function that returns the smallest positive integer larger than n whose digits are increasing. I think the increasing function works correctly. But what is the mistake in the function decrease? For the input decreasing(100) it returns 11 rather than 110.

```
# the next integer whose digits are increasing.
def increasing(n):
    asastring = str(n)
    length = len(asastring)
    if asastring == "9"*length:
        return "1"*(length+1)
    if length == 1:
        return int(n)+1

    if length >= 2:
        firstcharacter = asastring[0]
        secondcharacter = asastring[1]
        if int(firstcharacter) > int(secondcharacter):
            return int(str(firstcharacter)*length)
        if firstcharacter == secondcharacter:
             return firstcharacter+str(increasing(int(asastring[1:])))
        if int(firstcharacter) < int(secondcharacter):
            if secondcharacter == "9":
                return str(int(firstcharacter)+1) * len(str(n))
            return firstcharacter+str(increasing(int(asastring[1:])))

# the next integer whose digits are decreasing.
def decreasing(n):
    asastring = str(n)
    length = len(asastring)
# First the case where we need to add a digit.
    if asastring == "9"*length:
        return "1"+"0"*length
# Now we know that the next integer has the same number of digits as the original number.
    if length == 1:
        return int(n)+1
    if length >= 2:
        firstcharacter = asastring[0]
        secondcharacter = asastring[1]
        if int(firstcharacter) > int(secondcharacter):
            endpart = str(((asastring[1:3])))
            value = firstcharacter + str(decreasing(int(asastring[1:])))
            return str(firstcharacter) + str(decreasing(int(asastring[1:])))
        if int(firstcharacter) == int(secondcharacter):
            return decreasing(firstcharacter+str(decreasing(int(asastring[1:]))))
        if int(firstcharacter) < int(secondcharacter):
            return str(int(firstcharacter)+1)+'0'*(length-1)

i=100
print(increasing(i))
print(decreasing(i))
```

Comment: If 110 is considered decreasing, why isn't 100 itself? Shouldn't the answer be 210?

Comment: It is decreasing but I was looking a function that returns the next smallest integer. I think the next largest decreasing number larger that 100 is 110 and then 200, 210, 211, 220, 221, 222, 300, and so on.

Comment: Oops. Of course there has to be 111 between 110 and 200.

Comment: There is a problem with conversion `int(asastring[1:])` where you get 0 no matter how many zeros are there.

Comment: I don't believe your `increasing()` function works correctly either.  For example, for the block of numbers from 190 to 198, it consistently returns 222 when it should be returning 199.  I believe I've fixed this issue in my answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple intertwined issues that need to be addressed.  The naming of these two functions is a source of confusion.  If we follow the logic, then the function `increasing()` should be called `nondecreasing()` and similarly, the function `decreasing()` should be called `nonincreasing()`.  It's the difference between > (greater than) and >= (greater than or equal).

The next confusion is what type do these functions *accept* and *return*?  If we examine what the *working* `increasing()` function returns, we get:

```
str return "1"*(length+1)
int return int(n)+1
int return int(str(firstcharacter)*length)
str return firstcharacter+str(increasing(int(asastring[1:])))
str return str(int(firstcharacter)+1) * len(str(n))
str return firstcharacter+str(increasing(int(asastring[1:])))
```

If we similarly look at how the `increasing()` deals with its own internal recursive calls to see what it thinks it accepts and returns, we get:

```
int -> int  return firstcharacter+str(increasing(int(asastring[1:])))
int -> int  return firstcharacter+str(increasing(int(asastring[1:])))
```

So here's an attempted rework of `increasing()`, aka `nondecreasing()`, that tries to make it consistently accept an `int` and return an `int`:

```
def nondecreasing(n):  # aka increasing()
    as_string = str(n)
    length = len(as_string)

    if as_string == "9" * length:
        return int("1" * (length + 1))

    if length == 1:
        return int(n) + 1

    first_digit, second_digit, second_digit_onward = as_string[0], as_string[1], as_string[1:]

    if first_digit > second_digit:
        return int(first_digit * length)

    if first_digit == second_digit:
        return int(first_digit + str(nondecreasing(int(second_digit_onward))))

    if as_string == first_digit + "9" * (length - 1):
        return int(str(int(first_digit) + 1) * length)

    return int(first_digit + str(nondecreasing(int(second_digit_onward))))
```

The `decreasing()`, aka `nonincreasing()`, function is more problematic.  It relies on its ability to accept an `int`, or a `str` upon internal calls, to solve the problem.

Discussing these sort of issues, and not making other programmers rediscover them, are what code comments are all about.

I don't believe the above issue precludes `nonincreasing()` from consistently *returning* an `int`:

```
def nonincreasing(n):  # aka decreasing()
    as_string = str(n)
    length = len(as_string)

    if as_string == "9" * length:
        return int("1" + "0" * length)

    if length == 1:
        return int(n) + 1

    first_digit, second_digit, second_digit_onward = as_string[0], as_string[1], as_string[1:]

    if first_digit > second_digit:
        return int(first_digit + str(nonincreasing(second_digit_onward)))

    if first_digit == second_digit:
        remaining_digits = str(nonincreasing(second_digit_onward))
        second_digit = remaining_digits[0]
        n = first_digit + remaining_digits

    if first_digit < second_digit:
        return int(str(int(first_digit) + 1) + '0' * (length - 1))

    return int(n)
```

The key to fixing this function was to remove the `return` statement from the penultimate `if` clause and instead fix up the data and let it fall through to the next `if` clause to see if the results need repair or not.

I believe @devender22's insight about `int()` casting is a crucial one but I don't believe the accompanying solution is valid as it generates large blocks of incorrect results (e.g. 990 through 998 all go to 1000 when they should simply be bumped up by 1).

In order to check my `nonincreasing()` function with all of its cases, I wrote a less efficient, non-recursive solution, without separate cases, using completely different Python operators:

```
def nonincreasing(n):

    def is_increasing(n):
        string = str(n)

        return any(map(lambda x, y: y > x, string, string[1:]))

    while is_increasing(n + 1):
        n += 1

    return n + 1
```

And then made sure the two implementations agreed on their output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the int type casting done in the recursive calls as int('00') is converting your number to zero(basically removing all starting zeros) and shortening the length of your string. Just remove that casting.. remaining code is working fine:

```
def decreasing(n):
    asastring = str(n)
    length = len(asastring)
# First the case where we need to add a digit.
    if asastring == "9"*length:
        return "1"+"0"*length
# Now we know that the next integer has the same number of digits as the original number.
    if length == 1:
        return int(n)+1
    if length >= 2:
        firstcharacter = asastring[0]
        secondcharacter = asastring[1]
        if int(firstcharacter) > int(secondcharacter):
            return str(firstcharacter) + str(decreasing(asastring[1:]))
        if int(firstcharacter) == int(secondcharacter):
            return decreasing(firstcharacter+str(decreasing(asastring[1:])))
        if int(firstcharacter) < int(secondcharacter):
            return str(int(firstcharacter)+1)+'0'*(length-1)
```

Comment: I admittedly get confused by the problem's logic, but I think there's still a bug here as 110  returns 200 when it should return 111.  I believe it's due to the two recursive calls to `decreasing()` in the penultimate `if` statement.  As this bumps the number twice.